# Using the new view bindings in an Android Kotlin application

Tags: android, kotlin, view, binding

I tried to follow this Traversy Media tutorial on creating a simple ToDo appliaction on Android https://youtu.be/BBWyXo-3JGQ.
However, the way they've written the application no longer works as Android stopped supporting the Synthetic view bindings.

I tried to rewrite the bindings myself, however the application now only displays new tasks with the "Example" name instead of the custom name that you fill for each task.
Clearly the problem seems to be in the views.
Here are my class files.

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.todo

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.View
import com.example.todo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var toDoAdapter: ToDoAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view: View = binding.root
        setContentView(view)

        toDoAdapter = ToDoAdapter(mutableListOf(), layoutInflater)
        binding.RVToDoItems.adapter = toDoAdapter
        binding.RVToDoItems.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        binding.BTNAddToDo.setOnClickListener {
            val toDoTitle = binding.ETToDoTitle.text.toString()
            if (toDoTitle.isNotEmpty()) {
                val todo = ToDo(toDoTitle)
                toDoAdapter.addToDo(todo)
                binding.ETToDoTitle.text.clear()
            }
        }

        binding.BTNDeleteDoneToDos.setOnClickListener {
            toDoAdapter.deleteDoneToDos()
        }
    }
}
```

ToDo.kt

```
package com.example.todo

data class ToDo(
    val title: String,
    var isChecked: Boolean = false
)
```

ToDoAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.todo

import android.content.ClipData.Item
import android.graphics.Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.todo.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.example.todo.databinding.ItemTodoBinding

class ToDoAdapter(
    private val todos : MutableList<ToDo>,
    private val inflater: LayoutInflater
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ToDoAdapter.ToDoViewHolder>() {

    private val binding : ItemTodoBinding = ItemTodoBinding.inflate(inflater);

    class ToDoViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ToDoViewHolder {
        return ToDoViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(
                R.layout.item_todo,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    fun addToDo(todo: ToDo) {
        todos.add(todo)
        notifyItemInserted(todos.size - 1)
    }

    fun deleteDoneToDos() {
        todos.removeAll { todo ->
            todo.isChecked
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun toggleStrikeThrough(TVToDoTitle: TextView, isChecked: Boolean) {
        if (isChecked) {
            TVToDoTitle.paintFlags = TVToDoTitle.paintFlags or STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG
        }
        else {
            TVToDoTitle.paintFlags = TVToDoTitle.paintFlags and STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG.inv()
        }
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return todos.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ToDoViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currTodo = todos[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            binding.TVToDoTitle.text = currTodo.title
            binding.CBDone.isChecked = currTodo.isChecked
            toggleStrikeThrough(binding.TVToDoTitle, currTodo.isChecked)
            binding.CBDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
                toggleStrikeThrough(binding.TVToDoTitle, isChecked)
                currTodo.isChecked = !currTodo.isChecked
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Can anyone kindly help me rewrite the app https://github.com/philipplackner/TodoList into a fully working version using the newest View Bindings?
There seems to be a mistake in the way I use my View Bindings.

I tried to use com.example.todo.databinding as you would with

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.
```

instead however the way I used the databindings seems to be at fault and new items don't refresh as expected. I can only create new tasks with title "Example", and deleting checked items doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have found two mistakes you made.

1. You don't pass a binding to a view holder. So, View holders cannot update as you update bindings.

```kotlin
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ToDoViewHolder {
    return ToDoViewHolder(
        // inflate a ItemTodoBinding and pass it to a TodoViewholder
        ItemTodoBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    )
}
```

2. TodoAdapter does not need a binding object. But, View holders do.

```kotlin
// make the view holder have a binding
class ToDoViewHolder(val binding: ItemTodoBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)
```

```kotlin
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ToDoViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val currTodo = todos[position]

    // update view holders with their bindings
    holder.binding.apply {
        TVToDoTitle.text = currTodo.title
        CBDone.isChecked = currTodo.isChecked
        toggleStrikeThrough(TVToDoTitle, currTodo.isChecked)
        CBDone.setOnCheckedChangeListener{ _, isChecked ->
            toggleStrikeThrough(TVToDoTitle, isChecked)
            currTodo.isChecked = !currTodo.isChecked
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
This doesn't fix the problem, however may be a good step towards the solution.

The second guide is basically just a naming convention, e.g. renaming itemView to binding.
The first guide is a new way to return the ItemToDo view which may be more fitting, that is using bindings instead of R.layout.*

Comment: @mastermism Sorry, I made a mistake on the second guide. the `binding` property's type should be `ItemTodoBinding`, not `View`. I just fixed the answer.